# Python dictionary too slow for crosscomparison, improvements?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, comparison, iteration

I am currently struggling with a performance issue when using Python dictionaries. I have a few huge dicts (up to 30k entries), and I want to do a cross-comparison on these entries. So, if one entry (identifier is a key) is given, how many other dicts contain this entry with this key, too? It currently takes up to 5h on my machine, but it should work in about a few minutes to make sense for my tool. I already tried to remove entries to make the search more efficient.

`all_cached_data` is a list with these lists of dicts. `sources` is a list with information about the lists in `all_cached_data`.

```
appearsin_list = []

# first, get all the cached data
sources = sp.get_sources()
all_cachedata = [0]*len(sources)
for source in sources:
    iscached = source[8]
    sourceid = int(source[0])
    if iscached == "True":
        cachedata, _ = get_local_storage_info(sourceid)
    else:
        cachedata = []
    all_cachedata[sourceid-1] = cachedata

# second, compare cache entries
# iterate over all cached sources
for source in sources:
    sourceid = int(source[0])
    datatype = source[3]
    iscached = source[8]
    if verbose:
        print("Started comparing entries from source " + str(sourceid) +
              " with " + str(len(all_cachedata[sourceid-1])) + " entries.")

    if iscached == "True":
        # iterate over all other cache entries
        for entry in all_cachedata[sourceid-1]:
            # print("Comparing source " + str(sourceid) + " with source " + str(cmpsourceid) + ".")
            appearsin = 0
            for cmpsource in sources:
                cmpsourceid = int(cmpsource[0])
                cmpiscached = cmpsource[8]
                # find entries for same potential threat
                if cmpiscached == "True" and len(all_cachedata[cmpsourceid-1]) > 0 and cmpsourceid != sourceid:
                        for cmpentry in all_cachedata[cmpsourceid-1]:
                            if datatype in cmpentry:
                                if entry[datatype] == cmpentry[datatype]:
                                    appearsin += 1
                                    all_cachedata[cmpsourceid-1].remove(cmpentry)
                                    break

            appearsin_list.append(appearsin)
            if appearsin > 0:
                if verbose:
                    print(entry[datatype] + " appears also in " + str(appearsin) + " more source/s.")
            all_cachedata[sourceid-1].remove(entry)

avg = float(sum(appearsin_list)) / float(len(appearsin_list))

print ("Average appearance: " + str(avg))
print ("Median: " + str(numpy.median(numpy.array(appearsin_list))))
print ("Minimum: " + str(min(appearsin_list)))
print ("Maximum: " + str(max(appearsin_list)))
```

I would be very thankful for some tips on speeding this up.

Comment: What possibly made you think a quadruply nested loop in a scripting language would be a good approach to handling 30k of data?

Comment: This is exactly my problem and I, sadly, know, that this is not a good approach, why I came here. But as a matrixmultiplication, this seems just to be as it is: not fast and not really, in an algorithmitic-way, increasable. So i have to deal with it, and maybe there something faster. I already thought about numpy, but i dont know how to map my data into numpy arrays.

Comment: You need to fix your algorithm. It's not clear which parts of the code are important and which aren't, e.g. `cmpsource[8]`. Rather than explain all the terms, write some new code, which is just the mechanism that you want, i.e. comparison and removal, with some simple data. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your constructive reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your algorithm can be improved; nested loops are not great in this case. I also think that Python is probably not the best for this particular purpouse: use SQL to do compare and search in a big amount of data. You can use something like [sqlite_object](https://github.com/hospadar/sqlite_object) to convert your data set in a SQLite db and query it.
If you want to go ahead with pure Python, you can try to compile your script with Cython; you can have some resonable improvements in speed.

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html

Then you can improve your code with some static type hinting:

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#static-typing

Comment: Thank you very much. In this case it is possible to use SQL, but I seriously didnt think about that. Should be lots faster than.